# Ошибка при выполнении множественных запросов requests

Tags: python, api, requests

Мне нужно в цикле выполнить несколько запросов, чтобы в зависимости от города собрать в `catalog` данные для разных городов.

```
cities_list = ['москва', 'санкт-петербург', 'екатеринбург'.............]
url_services = 'https://some url'

catalog = {}
for city in cities_list:
    params = {'city': city}
    try:
        response = requests.post(url_services, json=params, verify=False)
        response = response.json()
        catalog[city] = response['result']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='..........', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /local/api/ ............ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at ...........>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
```

Ошибка стандартно вылетает после второго запроса.

Точками заполнены закрытые данные сервиса и АПИ.

Помогите, в чем проблема? time.sleep не помогает.